# Quartz Scheduler, unlimited attempts to connect with database

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler (v 2.2.1) with spring boot application. When the application database was accidentally down, quartz logged enormous amount of following log messages. The same error message is logged repeated in very short amount of time which made the log file to consume all available disk space.

```
    2016-03-03_03:00:00.474 [schedulerFactoryBean_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Couldn't rollback jdbc connection. The connection is closed.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.rollback(SQLServerConnection.java:1954) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor602.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.rollback(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor602.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.rollback(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.rollbackConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3650) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3809) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
2016-03-03_03:00:00.474 [schedulerFactoryBean_QuartzSchedulerThread] WARN  o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Failed to override connection auto commit/transaction isolation.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getAutoCommit(SQLServerConnection.java:1909) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.setAutoCommit(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:90) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:66) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:191) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3784) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
2016-03-03_03:00:00.474 [schedulerFactoryBean_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Couldn't rollback jdbc connection. The connection is closed.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.rollback(SQLServerConnection.java:1954) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor602.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.rollback(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor602.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.rollback(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.rollbackConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3650) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3809) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
2016-03-03_03:00:00.474 [schedulerFactoryBean_QuartzSchedulerThread] WARN  o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Failed to override connection auto commit/transaction isolation.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getAutoCommit(SQLServerConnection.java:1909) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.setAutoCommit(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:90) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:66) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreCMT.java:191) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3784) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
```

I am using spring boot quartz auto configuration. The only quartz related configuration is the cron job expression in application.properties

Can anyone please help me, how I can configure quatrz to log this error once or try to reconnect after longer time period?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 2.2.1 has a bug which causes exception logging in the infinite loop in case of database failure. Please following jira for further details https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-470.

This error was fixed by downgrading the version to 2.2.0

Comment: This didn't work for me. Problem persists with v2.2.0.